# How to call a Cython's cdef function with memory view from a C program?

Tags: python, c, cython

I am new to Cython and trying to call a function with memory view defined in Cython using cdef function. I am using Mac OSx High Sierra 10.13.1. C code is written and compiled in Xcode(V9.1). '.pyx' file is compiled using python3

```
pvel.pyx

cdef public psvel(double [:] lcfarray, double [:]  fn,double [:]
   Q,int axis, int dl, double sR):
% few lines of code in python
% not shown here....

main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python/Python.h>
#include "pvel.h"

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    double lc[]={1.2345,2.4343,5.4443,6.554545};
    double f[]= {1,2};
    double Q1[]={10.0,25.0,50.0};
    int axis1[]={1,2,3};
    int dl1=4;
    double sR1=1024.0;
    psvel(*lc,*f,*Q1,axis1,dl1,sR1);
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

When I compile main.c in Xcode, I get the following error:

1.Redefinition of parameter '_Pyx_memviewslice' in pvel.h

2. Expected Identifier pvel.h

When I click on the error, the compiler highlights the error in pvel.h file at the following line:

```
__PYX_EXTERN_C PyObject *psvel(__Pyx_memviewslice, __Pyx_memviewslice,   __Pyx_memviewslice, int, int, doublevoid);
```

First error is highlighted at the second argument's position __Pyx_memviewslice and the second error (about identifier) is highlighted at the first occurence of 'int')

I used memory view (based on Cython's documentation for speed. Other than that I am not sure why it is even used. It will be helpful if someone can show me the right way to call the cdef function from C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memoryviews provide a fast way of accessing objects that have the Python buffer interface (such as Numpy arrays). However, they aren't really designed to be used from C and I don't know an easy way to do it.

I can think of two options here:

1. Change your Cython function to accept C pointers instead. Accessing the C pointers is fast (similar to memoryviews, possibly faster)

   ```
   cdef public psvel(double * lcfarray, double *  fn,double *
            Q,int axis, int dl, double sR):
   ```
2. Have a second `cdef` function that converts the C pointers to memoryviews. The advantage of this is that you can still easily call the memoryview function with Numpy arrays, and you keep some of the advantages of memoryviews (such as automatic bounds checking). To cast a pointer to a memoryview you need the pointer and its length: `<double [:length]>ptr`

   ```
   # no longer public - you're not calling it from C
   cdef psvel(double [:] lcfarray, double [:] fn,double [:]
            Q,int axis, int dl, double sR):
       # ...

   cdef public psvel_from_c(double * lcfarray, double * fn,double *
            Q,int axis, int dl, double sR):
       return psvel(<double[:len_of_lcfarray]>lcfarray,
                    <double[:len_of_fn]>fn,
                    # etc....
                    axis, dl, sR)
   ```

Comment: cdef public psvel_from_c(double *lcfarray, double *fn,double *Q,int axis, int     dl, double sR):
        return psvel(<double[:10]>lcfarray, <double[:10]>fn, <double[:10]>Q, <int> axis, <int> dl, <double> sR)
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pvel.pyx:20:17: Cannot assign type 'double[::1]' to 'double *'

Comment: And you did keep `psvel` accepting memoryviews (but removed the "public"?). Also you don't need to do `<int>` etc, since these are already the right type

Comment: Yes, I did keep psvel and removed public from psvel, as you posted. I removed <int> also. I ran it again, and the failure is same: pvel.pyx:20:17: Cannot assign type 'double[::1]' to 'double *'

Comment: I have `cdef psvel(double [:] lcfarray, double [:] fn,double [:] Q,int axis, int dl, double sR): pass` and then `cdef public psvel_from_c(double * lcfarray, double * fn,double * Q,int axis, int dl, double sR): return psvel(<double[:10]>lcfarray,                 <double[:10]>fn, <double[:10]>Q, axis, dl, sR)` and this compiles fine for me.

Comment: The order was wrong. I changed it as you suggested and it compiles well from .pyx to a .so file.